# I can't figure out my mistake in calculating the harmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity, divergent-series, harmonic-functions, harmonic-numbers

Let's say $a = H_{\infty}$, so $a = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}$. 
$$a = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\infty}$$
Now if we take $a - a + 1$ we get
$$a - a + 1 = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\infty} - (1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\infty}) + 1 $$
$$=1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\infty} - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} - \cdots - \frac{1}{\infty} = (1 - \frac{1}{2}) + (\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4}) + (\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{6}) + \cdots$$
$$=\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{6} + ... + \frac{1}{\infty}$$
That means that
$$a - a + 1 = 1 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{6} + ... + \frac{1}{\infty} = \frac{1}{2}a$$
$$1 = \frac{1}{2}a$$
$$a = 2 \cdot 1 = 2$$
Now since I now the harmonic series are divergent, I know the result I got is false. However, I tried to used the same trick that's used to proof that the Grandi's series ($\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1...)$ are equal to $\frac{1}{2}$. My only question is, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Are the definitions you are using the ones of calculus?

Comment: I guess, yes, but now I'm starting to doubt myself

Comment: Then you should realise that the result you claim for Grandi's series is actually false. The most notable flaw here is that, since there is no real number $a$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k=a$, evaluting $a-a+1$ makes no sense. And it's most likely the case for what you saw for Grandi's series.

Comment: Ah, that'd make a lot of sense! Could you maybe post that as an answer please, so that it can be shown as solved and you'd get rewarded appropriately?

Comment: Also, @G.Sassatelli if the Grandi's series ($\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \neq \frac{1}{2}$), then is it actually true that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n = \frac{1}{2}$? Since the proof I saw used the Grandi's series with a result of exactly $\frac{1}{2}$ (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-I6XTVZXww). Or is it just that that specific proof is false, and only Riemann Zeta can be used to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n = \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n$ is also divergent, so it's not true. The sum of the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x_k $ is defined as $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n x_k$ if the limit exists. That definition is the only real way to understand them. Other claims are trickery or perhaps heuristic methods employed by physicists etc.

Comment: (1). There is no real number $1/\infty.$ (2). The notation $x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n$ means  $x=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^nx_j$ which means $\forall r>0\;\exists n_r\;\forall n>n_r\;( |x-\sum_{j=1}^nx_j|<r). $ No more & no less. (3). Treating  addition or subtraction on the collections of terms of infinite series  as if they were sums of finite collections is not valid in most cases. & if the series diverge you are almost certain to get nonsense by doing that.

Comment: The trick one can use to (re)sum the Grandi series works because of some growth conditions on the general terms which are not satisfacted by the harmonic series, those kind of results belong to the so called "summability theory" and "tauberian theory" if you are interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the answers are given in the comments, so if the users who posted these comments could post it as answer, this answer will be deleted and their answer will be chosen as accepted answer. Until then, here is a summary. To **sum it up** (*padum tss*):

The main mistake made is assuming that $\frac{1}{2}$ is the answer to Grandi's series ($\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n$), which it's not (the Grandi's series are divergent). Because of that, we can't use the same trick, since it will not result in the right answer. $a$ is not a real number, and therefore should not be treated like one. That basically is the mistake I made.

EDT: What I also just found out is that I don't subtract the $\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{5}, \frac{1}{7}$ and all other odd fractions, so 
$$a - a + 1 = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{5} + ... \frac{1}{\infty}$$
which of course limits to $0$. That makes quite a bit more sense, even though, as stated above, is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do the step on line 5, because of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem.

Comment: How come? Since I don't do $1 - 1 + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{3} + ...$ which indeed converges to 0, as your link says, but I use $1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{6} + ...$ which never is mentioned in the article.

Comment: @SuperSjoerdie In general, you cannot change the positions of terms in an infinite series. See [this Math SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2051691/what-is-wrong-with-the-proof-for-ln2-frac12-ln2) which (falsely) shows that $\ln 2 = \frac{1}{2} \ln 2$ using a similar method.